# Why is the p background not positioning correctly?

Tags: css, html, background

Can you please tell me why the p background is not showing?

The issue is only in firefox. Firebug is showing the div positioning behind the floated divs above, but can't figure out why. I know the image is there and showing, but is behind the other divs.

So, can you please tell me why Firefox is assuming div#about-gmm is behind the two divs above.

http://responsedriver.com/newsite/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `clear: both` on your #about-gmm div. Otherwise, the floated divs aren't part of the content flow, and so the paragraph appears under them.

Comment: perfect, thanks! Question though. I had a clear: both above the #about-gmm div. How come that didn't correct the issue ?

Comment: The hr is set to display:none, so the layout engine in Firefox (and Safari and Chrome, btw) doesn't bother to include it in the content flow. Apparently IE does.

Comment: No, IE 7 doesn't care about the hr either. It's something else about the layout that it gets wrong...

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 displays it the same way as Firefox does.

The two div elements above the `p` elemtn are floating, so they don't push it down (except in IE 7 that gets it wrong).

Simply add `clear:both;` to the `#about-gmm` style.

Alternatively, replace the hidden hr element (that doesn't affect anything as it's hidden) with a div element with the style `clear: both; height: 0; overflow: hidden;`. (The styles other than `clear` is so that it doesn't take up space in IE 6 and IE 7.)